# Sending Data to Online Php Script

Tags: php, ios, uitextfield

Im in the process of trying to get users input data (From a UItextfiled) across to an online php script however i cant seem to get it working and not sure where im going wrong my coding is as follows;

```
- (IBAction)sendPost:(id)sender {
// Create your request string with parameter name as defined in PHP file
NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&surname=%@",_firstnameresult.text,_surnameresult.text];

// Create Data from request
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mckenziedave.co.uk/client_files/gcap/test"]];
// set Request Type
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
// Set content-type
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
// Set Request Body
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
// Now send a request and get Response
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
// Log Response
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",response);

}
```

And the online PHP ;

```
<?php
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $surname = $_POST['surname'];

echo echo $name.','.$surname;
?>
```

It loads the php when i check the debugger it for some reason isnt changing the 'name' or 'surname' with the fields.
I have been stuck on this a while now and really not sure what to do...

Comment: I have been trying different ways for an hour but it still isn't changing or sending any data to the php, just loading it... Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.php` extension to the `test` file in the server and also in the ios program posted above.

Comment: Thank you so much! Cant believe it was something this simple!!

Comment: Sometimes it happens and do upvote the answer as it is useful. ;)